# Scroll inside a div in UIWebView like iAd does

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, uiwebview, scroll

suppose the UIWebView is full screen, the html&css is simply like this:

```
<body><div id="wrapper" style="height:320px;width:460px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;display:block;overflow-x:none;overflow-y:scroll;">
    <ol style="width:100%;">//Its height is much bigger than 320px
    /* blablablablablabla */</ol>
</div></body>
```

When set UIWebView's UIScroller.bounces = YES, the page simply bounce up and down, no scroll for `<ol/>`.

When set UIWebView's UIScroller.bounces = NO, the page just acts as if frozen no matter how touched.

**What I want: the `<ol/>` scrolls the same as the UIWebView's scrolling.**

There is an example for this effect in iAd test. You can see it here:http://xiaolife.com/table_view_plain_declarative.html(I set it up on my own site, use safari to view and set UA as mobile safari), however iAd framework can not be used directly in UIWebview, and iAd seems too complicated for me.

the effect Apple did is almostly the same as the UIWebView does, including bounce and scroll bar.

But now, I simply want the `<ol>` to be **scrollable** at least, while I have no idea how :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank god I finally found this little code and it works great with a scroll bar,and bounce(not  easy to make it work) :) http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Comment: hey Xiao Xiao, would you like to share your code, i have see that link, but i still not too understand about that, thank you

Comment: for me, I simply wrote 'myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');' , and give the '<div id="wrapper"/>' a css saying 'position:relative;z-index:1;', and it's done. But don't forget to give the wrapper the right size.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can do this, much better

```
<div style="height:50px; overflow:scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"> 
test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah since the latest webkit on mobile supports -webkit-overflow-scrolling, it's solved perfectly. When I asked the question, it wasn't supported yet.